# C# avoid redundancy - convert derived type to base generic type and access common property

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, redundancy

I am beginning in C# and having some difficulties to solve the following problem.

Context :

- I have three classes (let's say A, B and C) that share some properties. Therefore they all are derived classes of an abstract class MySuperClass.
- Classes A, B and C contain a List called Values which will contain a specific type of element according to class A, B and C. For each class, there exist an other class ValuesA, ValuesB and ValuesC to explicit the content of List Values.
- ValuesA, ValuesB and ValuesC also share some properties and are derived classes of the abstract class MyGenericType

Here is the code for the abstract classes SuperClass and MyGenericType :

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T> where T : MyGenericType
{
    public SuperClass()
    {
         Values = new List<T>();
    }
    public List<T> Values {get; set;}

    //some other properties 
}
public abstract class MyGenericType
{
    public int property1 {get; set;}
    public int property2 {get; set;}
}
```

Here is the code for class A and ValuesA :
(NB class B (resp. C) and ValuesB (resp. ValuesC) have the same template only properties change (such as propertyA1 or propertyValuesA1)

```
public class A : SuperClass<AListValuesType>
{
    public A()
    {
        Values = new List<ValuesA>();
    }
    public int propertyA1 {get; set;}
    public bool propertyA2 {get; set;}
}

public class ValuesA : MyGenericType
{
    public bool propertyValuesA1;
    //some other properties
}
```

Problem : In my process, I have three objects of type A, B and C (accessible in all my ScriptMain class) where approximately the same transformations are applied. In order to avoid redundancy, I would like to use a common local variable at some point to store objects of type A, B and C and use it just as any object of type A, B or C.

Here is an example of my use with only object A and I need to do exactly the same with object B and C.

```
public class ScriptMain
{
    private A apiResultA;
    private B apiResultB;
    private C apiResultC;

    //some stuff

    public bool NextRow(string request)
    {
        //I would like to be able to have a variable apiResult that could store either apiResultA, apiResultB or apiResultC according to request value
        if (apiResultA != null)
        {
            //Need to be able to check if apiResultA.Values.Count=0
            //lot of generic stuff working for apiResultA, apiResultB and apiResultC
        }
        else
        {
            //lot of generic stuff working for apiResultA, apiResultB and apiResultC
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to cast my variable, to use interfaces... But I have not been able to solve my problem and I have no idea where to look next.

Thank you for reading this !

Comment: You will need a non-generic interface for your base class. How this interface could look like depends from the requirements. For example how do you use the `List` property. Do you really need a setter for it? The constructor is suggesting no. Or are you only getting values from it? An `ISuperClass` interface could have an `IList Values { get; }` (or IEnumerable) property, implemented explicitly in SuperClass. Then you can declare a variable of type ISuperClass and assign any class instances to it derived from SuperClass.

Comment: Very good stuff for good learners. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793351/avoid-redundancy-in-multiple-controllers-in-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface with covariance (*out T*):

```cs
public interface ISuperClass<out T> where T : MyGenericType
{
    IEnumerable<T> ValuesEnumerator { get; }  // IList dosen't support covariance, we have to use IEnumerable
    // Some other properties in your SuperClass 
}
```

*SuperClass* implements *ISuperClass*:

```cs
public abstract class SuperClass<T> : ISuperClass<T> where T : MyGenericType
{
    public SuperClass()
    {
        Values = new List<T>();
    }
    public List<T> Values { get; set; }
    public  IEnumerable<T> ValuesEnumerator => Values;
}
```

Now you can cast your results to *ISuperClass<MyGenericType>*:

```cs
public class ScriptMain
{
    private A apiResultA;
    private B apiResultB;
    private C apiResultC;

    //some stuff

    public bool NextRow(string request)
    {
        ISuperClass<MyGenericType> result = apiResultA;   // ISuperClass is covariant, so you can cast SuperClass<ValuesA> to ISuperClass<MyGenericType>
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.ValuesEnumerator.Count() == 0) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly ! FYI : I had to add using System.Linq; to be able to access Count Method